# Mostrar solo el primer elemento de una lista en templates

Tags: python, django, loops, template

Tengo una tabla en la cual muestro un objeto de la vista, esta son vacunas, lo que quiero es que por ejemplo si ya su pusieron esa vacuna, ya no me vuelva a salir el nombre de la vacuna, solo las fechas en las que se pusieron las vacunas.

#### template.html

```
<table width="100%" class="table-bordered">
  <caption style="text-align: center; font-weight:bolder; font-size: 20px; color:black">Vacunas aplicadas</caption>
</td>
    <td>Descripción</td>
    <td>Fecha de aplicación</td>
    <td>Nota</td>
</tr>
{% for vaccine in preventive %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ vaccine.vaccines }}</td>
        <td>{{ vaccine.vaccine_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ vaccine.vaccine_note}}</td>
        {% ifchanged vaccine.vaccines%}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

#### view.py

```
class PreventiveMedicineView(FormView):
    template_name = 'clipboard_medicinapreventiva.html'
    form_class = PrevMedicineForm

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        vac = self.request.POST['description']
        vaccines = Vaccines.objects.get(description=vac)
        vaccine_date = self.request.POST['vaccine_date']
        vaccine_note = self.request.POST['vaccine_note']

        if not vaccine_date:
            vaccine_date=datetime.datetime.now().date()

        patient=Patient.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['id'])
        clipboard_patient = Clipboard.objects.get(patient=patient)


        prev_medicine = PreventiveMedicine(clipboard=clipboard_patient,
                                           vaccines=vaccines,
                                           vaccine_date=vaccine_date,
                                           vaccine_note=vaccine_note)
        prev_medicine.save()
        success_url = reverse('preventive_medicine', kwargs={'id': patient.pk} )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        print form._errors
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PreventiveMedicineView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'patient': Patient.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['id']),
            'prev_medicine': PreventiveMedicine.objects.all(),
            'vaccines': Vaccines.objects.all(),
            'preventive': PreventiveMedicine.objects.filter(clipboard__patient=self.kwargs['id'])
        })
        return context
```

Por ejemplo este `form` me las muestra así:

```
tetanos--2016-01-02--test

tetanos--2015-10-03--descripcion.

H1N1   --2016-09-11--observaciones

hepatitis-2016-08-01--C
```

Bueno como lo dije arriba lo que quiero es que en el caso anterior de ejemplo somo me lo mostrara así

```
TETANOS

     --2016-01-02--test.

     --2015-10-03--descripcion.

H1N1   --2016-09-11--observaciones

hepatitis-2016-08-01--C
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar en la vista, como estas pasando el queryset???

Comment: Listo, añadi la vista.

Comment: Podrias poner el modelo tal cual está en models.py por favor? Porque creo que podría ayudarte obtener elementos con property()

Answer (score 1):

No me queda claro cuál es el criterio para saber si ya se han puesto una vacuna o no, pero en cualquier caso, mi consejo es definirlo o bien en la vista o bien en un Object Manager del modelo de la vacuna y comprobar el cumplimiento de este criterio con un {% if %} en el template. Por ejemplo, si hay un atributo "puesta" que sea un booleano de Vacuna, entonces puedes decir en el template:

```
{% for vaccine in preventive %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>
        {% if not vaccine.puesta %}
            {{ vaccine.vaccines }}
        {% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>{{ vaccine.vaccine_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ vaccine.vaccine_note}}</td>
    {% ifchanged vaccine.vaccines%}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos!
    Erick

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre una solución sencilla usando property de la siguiente manera:

Primero supongamos que tenés los siguientes dos modelos:

```
class Vacuna(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def obtener_datos(self):
        return DatosVacuna.objects.filter(vacuna_id = self)

    datos = property(obtener_datos) # Atributo property, obtengo todas las fechas y descripciones correspondientes a cada vacuna

class DatosVacuna(models.Model):
    vacuna_id = models.ForeignKey(Vacuna, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fecha_puesta = models.DateField()
```

Entonces después en el template podrías hacer uso de ese atributo property de la siguiente manera:

```
{% for vacuna in vacunas %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ vacuna.nombre }}</td>
        {% for dato in vacuna.datos %}
            <td>--{{ dato.fecha_puesta }}--{{dato.descripcion}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

De esta forma recorrés todos las fechas y descripciones correspondientes a cada vacuna. Además, al estar normlizado el modelo de base de datos no vas a tener problemas con los nombres de las vacunas, ya de esta forma evitás problemas a la hora de cambiar el nombre de una vacuna o escribirlo de forma incorrecta.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.